# What firewall settings are necessary for a render farm?

Tags: rendering, network

I don't use Blender myself, but it is installed in our teaching labs.  I'm the system administrator for these labs, and I'm trying to configure the computers so that one of our students can use them in a render farm configuration for a special event.  Specifically, I need to know how Windows Firewall should be configured.

In the old manual for Blender 2.6 I found a page titled [Networks in Blender rendering](https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc%3A2.6/Manual/Render/Performance/Netrender).  This seems to imply (but does not state outright) that only the machine running the Master server needs the firewall configured, that it requires only a single port to be opened, and that you can choose whatever port you like.  (There is no mention there of a default port, though I found some other posts suggesting that 8000 may be the usual choice.)

I couldn't find an equivalent page in the current manual.  If it makes any difference, we are running Blender 2.77a.

Will it be sufficient for me to open a single port, say 8000, and advise the student to use that?  Or is it more complicated than that?

Comment: I am pretty sure it is just port 8000 (the default when I switched to network render, and that also is where the web control ties in). And yes, it should only be the master that needs to have port 8000 open to it, as the client and slave will connect to it (the client provides the jobs and controls them, the slave just renders). Keep in mind that the master will not render the frames, you would need to open up a slave on that computer to get it to render (more important when you are dealing with few computers). However, I don't have a super advanced network setup to test this on and confirm.